# Showing a timestamp from a datetimestamp as either AM or PM

Tags: date, datetime, excel-formula

I have a number of `date/time` entries in a spreadsheet which I wish to reformat as follows

```
10/20/2014 13:00:00 (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) to show as 20/10/2014 PM

10/01/2014 08:00:00 (mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) to show as 01/10/2014 AM
```

I can convert and split the date out easily enough but I cannot get the `hh:mm:ss` to show as simply `AM` or `PM`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under **Format Cells**, choose the **Number** tab, select **Custom**, and enter this format:

```
dd/mm/yyyy AM/PM
```

You can also do this using the **TEXT** function:

```
=TEXT(Date,"dd/mm/yyyy AM/PM")
```

Comment: Simple as that. Thank you.